# Idle and Pandas-Python

Tags: python

I am trying to launch this code that I have found from a IPython notebook
(I also add some code like :interactive(True)...)
And my problem is when I use "run module" with Idle it launches the "data.plot" 
then it loads and nothing happens. The data.plot doesn't seem to work.

Thanks if you have any idea.

Note: Without "interactive(True)" a box show up with "Runtime error"

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import interactive
interactive(True)

# read data into a DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv('http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv', index_col=0)
print(data.head())

# print the shape of the DataFrame
print data.shape

# visualize the relationship between the features and the response using scatterplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True)
data.plot(kind='scatter', x='TV', y='Sales', ax=axs[0], figsize=(16, 8))
data.plot(kind='scatter', x='Radio', y='Sales', ax=axs[1])
data.plot(kind='scatter', x='Newspaper', y='Sales', ax=axs[2])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `display(data.plot(PARAMS))`. To import it try `from IPython.core.display import display`.

This worked for me in some iPython Notebooks.

Comment: I have an error "NameError: name 'display' is not defined" which library should I add ?